# how to Add the Telegram BOT to the group with command?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I have a Telegram bot and many Telegram group lists.

I want to add this bot to the group with command automatically and I don't want to do this manually.

I have already tried this code:

```
https://telegram.me/[botname]?startgroup=foo
```

I don't want to click **manually** on this link.

Is there any way that i can do this?

Comment: please post the actual code you tried rather than a link to a website that may die.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call them with `file_get_contents()` or `curl`?

```php
// Place your group names or IDs. These a some ramdon pseudo UUIDs
$groups = ["d511da1d-38b5-4a72-b449-f06412ca62a6", "9385d5bd-7f11-4436-9096-5af740bceb62", "b67c8b5a-4cde-408d-ab5f-954892341946", "2b450377-60c0-40fb-9604-5c8d134c1339", "31c8cbd9-1f4c-46d3-9d90-491d68ac930c"];

// Call the URL for each group
foreach($groups as $groupId) {
    file_get_contents("https://telegram.me/mybotname?startgroup=$groupId");
}
```

Comment: i know but i don't want manually after that link appears click on dialog .

Comment: Click on what dialog? Where do you see it? In the Telegram app on your phone?

Comment: when i use this code https://telegram.me/[botname]?startgroup=foo a dialog popup and i should select telegram app on windows to open te;egram and join to that group but i didn't this . i want list group id and with a for loop join to all group.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Code is not a URL. Where does the dialog pop up? Why should you select an app? When you use `file_get_contents()` nothing will pop up anywhere.

Comment: look my friend: i have 20 group links like this: https://t.me/Vitana_Corporation and i want to  use your code   file_get_contents("https://telegram.me/testbot?startgroup=Vitana_Corporation");  right? nothing happend but if i use that link in browsers it open a dialog for telegram can u test it?

Comment: Sure, because if you click that URL in a browser you are calling the website behind. But if you use PHP code, it will *NOT* be done in the browser, so no popup ever can come up. If you want the browser to "click" those links, then do it with JavaScript *IN* the browser.

Comment: If you run PHP locally on your system you should be able to do `system("https://telegram.me/mybotname?startgroup=$groupId");` and the default browser should open with that URL.

Comment: tnx. can i use group links instead of group id? and if answer is no how can i get group id of a group?

Comment: I am not sure if the group ID is mandatory, but I think it is. To get the group ID there is a bot you can add to tell you, otherwise you won't see it. Add `@BotFather` to your contacts to learn more about that.